# Multiple File Extension Rename with single command

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I received some important files via mail. There are about 150 files like these. The extensions of the files are named as zip1,zip2,zip3, zip_ etc. I just want to change the extension of these files back to zip using a single command to avoid the manual task of renaming each file.

Comment: Are the non-extension parts of the filenames unique, or is it the digit suffix that distinguishes them? Can you edit you post to include some actual examples?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
rename 's/zip[^.]*$/zip/' /path/to/directory/containing/the/files/*
```

Example:

```
$ ls
bar.zip2  egg.zip4  foo.zip1  spam.zip3  test.zip_
$ rename 's/zip[^.]*$/zip/' *
$ ls
bar.zip  egg.zip  foo.zip  spam.zip  test.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

This multiple rename task is easy to do using pyRenamer from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier. The following screenshot explains how to do it:

[image]

I know it's not the way to do it in the terminal as you requested, but this is an alternate way of doing it that you may find easier because you can browse to the files to be renamed in the pyRenamer window instead of typing the path.

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later pyRenamer has been replaced by either [GPRename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030996/how-can-i-install-pyrenamer-for-bionic/1031003#1031003) or the Smart File Renamer snap package (`sudo snap install smart-file-renamer`).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mmv.1.html) command (Install it by `sudo apt-get install mmv`):

```bsh
mmv -n '*.zip*' '#1.zip'
```

First * matches everything before *.zip* and second * matches everything after *.zip* and they become as group of matches with back-reference `#1` and `#2` respectively. And we only keep the first one with *.zip* at the end.

**Note:** With using `-n` option, `mmv` command runs as dry, so remove it to perform actual renaming.

---

Or through combination of [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) and [`mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mv.1.html) commands:

```bsh
find source/dir -type f -name '*.zip*' -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%.*}.zip"' sh_mv {} \;
```

- the `source/dir` specifies the path of source directory.
- `-type f` searches **f**iles only.
- `-name '*.zip*'` find those type of files that their names are like '*.zip*'
- `{}` represent the current file.
- Complete of `"${1%.*}.zip"`, stripes file extension and append `.zip` to file name.
- So `mv "$1" "${1%.*}.zip"` renames the current file to `*.zip`.

**Note:** Remove `echo` command after you ensure about dry run.

Comment: Why are you using `{}` in that weird way when `$0` is anyway being used? O.o

Comment: @muru edited answer